# Get all transactions on monday between 10 and 11am

Tags: django, datetime, django-models, transactions

I'm wondering if it is possible to use Django on a database of transaction to get all transaction that happened on a(ll) Monday(s) between 10 and 11.

For completeness here is the model definition:

```
class P1data(models.Model):
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=12)
    volume = models.DecimalField(max_digits=40, decimal_places=12)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`week_day`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#week-day) and [`hour`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#hour) lookups:

```
P1data.objects.filter(date_time__week_day=2, date_time__hour__range=(10, 11))
```

**UPDATE**: If `hour` lookup doesn't support `range` then try to use the combination of `lte`/`gte`:

```
P1data.objects.filter(date_time__week_day=2,
                      date_time__hour__gte=10,
                      date_time__hour__lte=11)
```

Comment: Seems i was a bit tot quick on this One. The hour filter doesn't seem to support ranges.

Comment: Hm, strange. Then try to use the `lte`/`gte` like in the update of my answer.